# Using the star sign in grep

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I am trying to search for the substring "abc" in a specific file in linux/bash

So I do:

```
grep '*abc*' myFile
```

It returns nothing.

But if I do:

```
grep 'abc' myFile
```

It returns matches correctly.

Now, this is not a problem for me. But what if I want to grep for a more complex string, say

```
*abc * def *
```

How would I accomplish it using grep?

Comment: grep itself doesn't support wildcards on most platforms.  You have to use egrep to use wildcards.  Shells have a different syntax.  "*" in the shell is <any string>.  In egrep it's an operator that says "0 to many of the previous entity".  In grep, it's just a regular character.

Comment: @PanCrit: `*` means the same thing in grep and egrep: it's a *quantifier* meaning zero or more of the preceding atom.  That's a completely different concept than the *wildcards* used by the shell.

Comment: @AlanMoore  Thanks for the update. I don't know when this changed, but you're correct that the modern `grep` supports most basic regular expressions. It used to be the case that you had to use egrep to get more than flat strings, but I see that grep has evolved.

Answer (score 189, accepted):

For such two-part matches, use `.*` between the two parts.

For instance:

`grep 'abc.*def' myFile`

will match a string that contains `abc` followed by `def` with something optionally in between.

---

The asterisk is just a [repetition operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), but you need to tell it what you repeat. `/*abc*/` matches a string containing ab and zero or more c's (because the second * is on the c; the first is meaningless because there's nothing for it to repeat). If you want to match anything, you need to say `.*` -- the dot means any character ([within certain guidelines](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)). If you want to just match abc, you could just say `grep 'abc' myFile`.

**Update based on a comment:**

`*` in a regular expression is not exactly the same as * in the console. In the console, * is part of a [glob construct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(Unix)), and just acts as a wildcard (for instance `ls *.log` will list all files that end in .log). However, in regular expressions, * is a modifier, meaning that it only applies to the character or group preceding it. If you want * in regular expressions to act as a wildcard, you need to use `.*` as previously mentioned -- the dot is a wildcard character, and the star, when modifying the dot, means find one or more dot; ie. find one or more of any character.

Comment: I think the questionner is confused about the difference between shell wildcards and regular expressions.  I also suspect that the more complicated expression would be: grep 'abc .* def' (at least one space present - possibly two as I wrote).

Comment: Actually, the questionner seems not to understand that 'abc' is not the same thing as '^abc$' :-D

Comment: Yes, i was confused between glob and full regular expressions. I use the * without a dot to mean matching anything on the shell.

Comment: grep `*` means "0 or more", and grep is greedy by default. Note that in grep **basic** regular expressions the metacharacters   `?`, `+` , `{` , `|` , `(` , and  `)` lose their special meaning. More info: [grep regexps](http://ss64.com/bash/grep-regex.html)

Comment: Please note that, according to [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html), in basic regular expressions (BRE), the asterisk looses its special meaning when used as the first character of the BRE or right after the caret (^). When using Extended regular expressions (ERE), this creates undefined behaviour. So `grep '*foo' file` searches for the substring `"*foo"` while `grep -E '*foo' file` is undefined.

Answer (score 48):

The dot character means match any character, so `.*` means zero or more occurrences of any character.  You probably mean to use `.*` rather than just `*`.

Comment: Dot is a meta character which accept any character except **new lines**.

Comment: For a programmatic way to convert `*` to `.*`, you can use sed search-and-replace: `echo 'test*' | sed 's/\*/\.\*/g'`

Answer (score 15):

Use grep -P - which enables support for Perl style regular expressions.

```
grep -P "abc.*def" myfile
```

Answer (score 13):

The "star sign" is only meaningful if there is something in front of it. If there isn't the tool (grep in this case) may just treat it as an error. For example:

```
'*xyz'    is meaningless
'a*xyz'   means zero or more occurrences of 'a' followed by xyz
```

Comment: The * is not meaningless; it just doesn't have its usual meaning (of repetition) but means "I'm a star".  It would match a line containing a star followed by x, y, and z.

Comment: @Jonathan It depends on the tool.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

grep ".*${expr}" - with double-quotes, preceded by the dot.
Where ${expr} is whatever string you need in the end of the line.

So in your case:

```
grep ".*abc.*" myFile
```

Standard unix grep.

Answer (score 6):

The expression you tried, like those that work on the shell command line in Linux for instance, is called a "[glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))". Glob expressions are not full [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), which is what grep uses to specify strings to look for. [Here](http://lwn.net/Articles/96687/) is (old, small) post about the differences. The glob expressions (as in "ls *") are interpreted by the shell itself.

It's possible to translate from globs to REs, but you typically need to do so in your head.

Comment: It's only a glob if it's parsed by the shell.  Since he is preserving the search string inside of single quotes, the shell leaves the string alone, and passed it intact in argv to grep.

Answer (score 4):

You're not using regular expressions, so your grep variant of choice should be `fgrep`, which will behave as you expect it to.

Comment: `fgrep` is now deprecated, `grep -f` should be used instead.

Comment: That's "grep -F".  Good ol' fgrep may be "deprecated", but they're not going to take it away while I'm still alive.

Answer (score 3):

Try grep -E for extended regular expression support

Also take a look at:

[The grep man page](http://www.ss64.com/bash/grep.html)

Answer (score 2):

'*' works as a modifier for the previous item.  So 'abc*def' searches for 'ab' followed by 0 or more 'c's follwed by 'def'.

What you probably want is 'abc.*def' which searches for 'abc' followed by any number of characters, follwed by 'def'.

Answer (score 1):

This may be the answer you're looking for:

```
grep abc MyFile | grep def
```

Only thing is... it will output lines were "def" is before OR after "abc"

Answer (score 1):

I summarize other answers, and make these examples to understand how the regex and glob work.

There are three files

```
echo 'abc' > file1
echo '*abc' > file2
echo '*abcc' > file3
```

Now I execute the same commands for these 3 files, let's see what happen.

(1)

```
grep '*abc*' file1
```

As you said, this one return nothing. `*` wants to repeat something in front of it. For the first `*`, there is nothing in front of it to repeat, so the system recognize this `*` just a character `*`. Because the string in the file is `abc`, there is no `*` in the string, so you cannot find it. The second `*` after c means it repeat `c` 0 or more times.

(2)

```
grep '*abc*' file2
```

This one return `*abc`, because there is a `*` in the front, it matches the pattern `*abc*`.

(3)

```
grep '*abc*' file3
```

This one return `*abcc` because there is a `*` in the front and 2 `c` at the tail. so it matches the pattern `*abc*`

(4)

```
grep '.*abc.*' file1
```

This one return `abc` because `.*` indicate 0 or more repetition of any character.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat a.txt
123abcd456def798
123456def789
Abc456def798
123aaABc456DEF
```

`*` matches the preceding character zero or more times.

```
$ grep -i "abc*def" a.txt


$
```

It would match, for instance "abdef" or "abcdef" or "abcccccccccdef".  But none of these are in the file, so no match.

`.` means "match *any* character"  Together with `*`, `.*` means match *any* character any number of times.

```
$ grep -i "abc.*def" a.txt
123abcd456def798
Abc456def798
123aaABc456DEF
```

So we get matches.
There are alot of online references about *regular expressions*, which is what is being used here.