# Bash - Getting the lines from a files which don't contain a specific pattern

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

I want to extract from a file all lines which don't content a specific pattern.

```
pattern="tmp/[...]/include/linux/*.h"
file contains:
17937;/home/[...]/tmp/[...]/include/linux/header.h;484;16;[Other text here]
37417;/home/[...]/tmp/[...]/src/file.cpp;1851;41;[Other text here]
17945;/home/[...]/tmp/[...]/include/linux/*/header.h;484;16;[Other text here]
```

The expected result is only the second line.

I've tried the bellow line and I get the entire content of the file:

```
grep -E -v $pattern file
```

It works only with the bellow line, but it is not enough:

```
grep -E -v .h file
```

How can I obtain the desired output?

Comment: grep -E -v "tmp/\\[...\\]/include/linux/.*\.h" will get the desired result based on your data.

Comment: Is not clear to me if the pattern that determines the lines be excluded is fixed, or is like using a wildcard: *.h  -> exclude all files with .h extension.

Comment: It is like using a wildcard. All lines with that pattern to be excluded (all .h lines with the same location)

Comment: Then you should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069302/using-the-star-sign-in-grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex needs to become `"tmp/\[\.\.\.]/include/linux/.*\.h"`

- The first square bracket need to be escaped, because having a list of characters between `[]` means "match one of those characters".
- The wildcard is associated with the character preceding it, so you need to put a dot before, to match any character.
- And you need to escape the dots if you want to match on them, otherwise they will match any character (it will work in your case though).

Comment: Escaping the first square bracket is also important.  See the section on `bracket expression` in the POSIX reg ex man page: `man re_format`.