# Why grep "file*.txt" output.txt does not work

Tags: regex, grep, glob

I have a file output.txt with content:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim80/doc/filetype.txt
/home/adminuser/trening/file1.txt
/home/adminuser/trening/file2.txt
```

Why `grep "file1.txt" output.txt` gives correct result and 
`grep "file*.txt" output.txt or grep "file?.txt" output.txt` gives no result?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` does not use glob pattern matching. It uses regex instead, so you should do:

```
grep "file.*\.txt" output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you did not know that.
Played around with it and got a new puzzle. According to what you say `grep file.\.* output.txt`  
should find only file1.txt and file2.txt

However search result gives:

`/help/files_write.txt  
      
/vim80/filetype.txt
/home/file1.txt  
/home/file2.txt  
`

Why is it so?

Comment: Please read about regex first. `*` matches zero to many occurrences of the preceding character, so `.*` matches any number of any characters, which is what the glob pattern `*` does in the one you included in your question. If you wish to match just one single character, your question would've included the glob pattern `file?.txt` instead, and the corresponding regex would be `file.\.txt`, where the unescaped `.` matches any character.

Comment: Yes, I have read that article. But I do not understand why `\.*` is the same as `.*`  

As I understood `grep file.\..* output.txt` should search for file?.any characters after dot. But it is searching for any characters after file?

Sorry, if this is confusing.

Comment: @Glebster You should quote the regex, or the backslash would be interpreted by the shell and not get passed to `grep`.

Comment: Attention to details is crutial with linux! Thank you

Comment: Also read up on quotes at https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes as I foresee those coming to bite you in the near future if you continue to use double quotes instead of single quotes around strings or scripts when you don't have a specific **need** to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The grep command handles the argument as regex, where the `*` has a different meaning than in the terminal (glob).
Related: [Using the star sign in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069302/using-the-star-sign-in-grep)