# dot in grep command being used as regex

Tags: grep

I'm trying to understand if bash is doing something with the string before passing it to grep or if grep uses basic regex searching by default. The man page and [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069302/using-the-star-sign-in-grep) don't really clarify

```
ss -an | grep "8.02"

u_dgr            UNCONN                 0                   0                                                                                                 * 820284002                                            * 820284001                
u_str            ESTAB                  0                   0                                                                                                 * 820283949                                            * 820287456
```

It looks like the `.` is being used in a regex fashion to match a single char. However, I would only expect this to happen when using `grep -e` or `grep -E`. If bash was intercepting the string I would expect special shell chars to be intercepted first such as `*` or `?`.

The man entry states I am using GNU grep 3.1

Comment: Try `grep -F`/`fgrep`.

Comment: Ever wondered where the name comes from? `g/re/p`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I have immediately found the answer after RTFMing a little closer

> -G, --basic-regexp
> Interpret PATTERN as a basic regular expression (BRE, see below).  This is the default.

"This is the default" - I assume means this is the default behaviour if no flags are passed?

Comment: yes, and you can use `-F` to override this and match the expression as a fixed string

Comment: been stuck on this for a while, although i did read the manual but didn't pay attention to it